# cannot assess rails app on amazon ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon EC2 and tried to deploy a rails project. 
I have install nginx/passenger and successfully made nginx server run.

I started my rails project with name "forfun"
then I set the root of nginx to /home/ubuntu/rails/forfun/public

I initialized a file named "index.html", then I could see the page in browser
(http://[my ip]:80)

However, what i really wanna see is the welcome page of rails app.

I tried do remove index.html and see what i got. I saw 404 Forbidden error. 
/var/log/nginx/error.log reveals that  directory index of "/home/ubuntu/rails/forfun/public/" is forbidden

What step i actually missed?

by the way, do i need to do "rails server" while nginx is running?

ps:
(1) /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
    http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.26;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby;
    ... 
        server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  52.196.XX.XXX;#my amazon public ip
            root /home/ubuntu/rails/forfuni/public;
        }
```

(2)/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
    server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /home/ubuntu/rails/forfun/public;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Comment: Does ec2 security group allow access to port 80. You can see in on ec2 console.

Comment: You mean the welcome to rails page that shows info like which version of rails is installed etc?

Comment: @Shishir, yes, ec2 security group do allow access to port 80, and 3000

Answer (score 0):

Try adding /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name  52.196.XX.XXX;#my amazon public ip;

 passenger_enabled on;
 passenger_app_env development; #or whatever rails env you want.
```

The whole process of deploying a rails app using nginx/passenger is documented [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04). See the nginx section.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04